# Excel VBA determine grouped rows in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In excel vba I can group rows in a worksheet using

```
NewSheet.rows("15:22").Group
```

But how can I determine which rows are already grouped in a worksheet?

Comment: Check the `OutlineLevel` of the rows, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code below to scan all rows with data in "NewSheet", and check per row if it's already grouped.

```
' scan all rows in your sheet
For i = 2 To lastRow

    ' check isf current row is grouped
    If NewSheet.Rows(i).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
        ' do something

    End If
Next i
```