# Is there a way to copy grouping from another workbook when copying in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy sheet from one workbook into another. I have a separate function to cycle through files (sources) within the parent folder and copy Summary tabs from the files into the master file in its designated tabs. Is there a way to preserve horizontal (rows) grouping the same as in the source files when copied to the master workbook? The code I've tried is below, but grouping doesn't go through.

```
Private Function CopyAndPaste(wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet)
    wsCopy.Range("A1:Z500").EntireRow.Copy
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    wsCopy.Range("A1:Z500").EntireRow.Copy
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
End Function
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a function? You should change this to a `Sub`. Either way, grouping is a column (or row) property, not a cell property so there is no reason to expect copying a cell would also copy groupings. You will have to check the groupings on your source sheet (`wsCopy`) and then apply the groupings to the new sheet (`wsDest`). Note the column indexes may not align so you will also have to account for that... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722679/excel-vba-determine-grouped-rows-in-worksheet) is an example to find rows that are grouped

Comment: If you copy the entire column the groupings will carry over so maybe you can do that and then delete rows that are not of interest.  Again, do this with a `Sub`

Comment: Why don't you copy the whole sheet? Use `wsCopy.Copy`

Comment: I would advise against this too. Usually you want to identify the 'minimal/complete' data set. If you know the scope of the columns you need then just grab those. Grabbing the entire sheet is complete but far from minimal

Comment: Yeah, I tried whole data sheet and remove previous when updating, but new pages throw #REF! error on calculation tabs (even if I turn off automatic calculations). 
@urdearboy I have it as a function in sub cause there are a few checks going in the same process (check setup page for file names and tabs, cycle through the folder files, etc). I'll check the advised solution. It is just I was under the impression that grouping sits under formatting (when I use format painter it pulls grouping through, but that's too much manual process to update it every time)

Answer (score 0):

To copy grouping it should be the following following:

```
wsCopy.Range("1:500").EntireRow.Copy
wsDest.Range("1:500").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```